# I am trying to 'count' the sum of specific letters in a column that are associated with a set of specific letters in another column of the same row

Tags: excel, sum, cell, criteria

I'm building the spreadsheet for my company and we are using letters A through F to simplify the result of a lead(potential appointment) in column L20:L999999.  Our sales agents initials are in column P20:P999999.  Each lead occupies a row, with each column containing different bits of information.  For example, the letter 'B' in column L20:L999999 represents a potential appointment that was not set up correctly by the sales agent and lost due to their mistake.  I am trying to get Excel to count how many "B"s a particular sales agent has. 
If it doesn't post a picture, please allow me to email it to you or something.  This would be so much help.

I'll try to get a picture: ![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPK2l.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a COUNTIFS statement is what you're after. Something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(L20:L999999,"=B",P20:P999999,"=LMP")
```

However, if you want to do it by reading the 'Legend' value given in cell I2 by using a lookup-style function (in particular, INDEX & MATCH) I think you have to un-merge the values in J13:K18, and then use:

```
=COUNTIFS(L20:L999999,INDEX(J13:L18,MATCH(I2,J13:J18,0),3),P20:P999999,"=LMP")
```